# Deploy ASP.NET Application to AWS from Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, azure-devops

i need some advice about continuous deployment within Visual Studio Team Service. To be honest, i am quite new in this area, so forgive this silly question because i can't find any reference for AWS but only Azure.

My idea is i can deploy asp.net application to AWS EC2 which is built from VSTS source control.

**My current scenario is:**

1. I had source control which contain asp.net application code inside VSTS.
2. I created build definition which build the source code and produce artifact.
3. I created release definition, which copy artifact to remote AWS EC2 instance.
4. ....

I don't have any idea to continue the next step, could you give advice what i should do next ? Or any better scenario ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I don't see any tasks which can directly deploy to AWS, so the only way this seems possible if you create your own task or use powershell or bash along with AWS cli to deploy your artifact. The process would be something like this

1. Download the artifact in a release. This is default if you link the artifact.
2. Make sure the agent machine that you are using has [AWS CLI for Powershell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) or [AWS Shell](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) if you are using bash.
3. You can then write a powershell or bash script which will utilize aws cli to deploy your artifact to AWS.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. About agent machine, can i modify hosted agent from the VSTS ? or should i have my own agent ?

Comment: In this case, I would advise you to have your own agent since you will need aws-cli which isn't there on hosted agent. 

But if you are stuck on hosted agent, you can write an script to install aws-cli in one of the steps and then use it. This will just increase your deploy time.

Comment: @IPutuYogaPermana You need to use your own agent. I don't think you can install AWS CLI on hosted agent.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering about this in the future, AWS just released the [AWS Tools for VSTS](https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/) to the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools). These tools contain a number of tasks you can use to work with AWS services such as S3, CodeDeploy, Elastic Beanstalk, Lambda and CloudFormation from within a VSTS or TFS environmemt.

We also just published a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-net-web-applications-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-visual-studio-team-services/) about using the tools to publish ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core applications to AWS from within VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options for you. A tutorial to explain how to get this running is given below.

How to Build a CI/CD Pipeline Using AWS CodeDeploy and Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS)
(For hybrid/complex deployments, you can use this. You can deploy IIS websites, MSI packages, services, exe). The beauty of this is that with a single deployment you can deploy to both on premises and cloud environment.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIE0P3m9eEY

How to Integrate AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) or (VSTS)
(for IIS websites/batch jobs you can use this)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRLZZefLDqU

How to Integrate AWS Cloudformation with Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS)
(fully infrastructure automation and manage infrastructure as code)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WU93NJT0_3s